# script to compare two large 900 x 900 comma delimited files

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have tried awk but havent been able to perform a diff for every cell 1 at a time on both files. I have tried awk but havent been able to perform a diff for every cell 1 at a time on both files. I have tried awk but havent been able to perform a diff for every cell 1 at a time on both files.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide us with an example of what your input looks like (the example **doesn't** have to be 900x900) and what your goal is. If you've made an attempt, include that as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a rough answer, possibly the simplest thing is to do something like:

```
tr , \\n file1 > /tmp/output
tr , \\n file2 | diff - /tmp/output
```

That will convert each file to one column and run diff.  You can compute the cells that differ from the line numbers of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way with awk without accounting for newlines inside fields,quoted commas etc.

Print the same

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=",|"RS}a[FNR]==$0;{a[NR]=$0}' file{,2}
```

Print differences

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=",|"RS}FNR!=NR&&a[FNR]!=$0;{a[NR]=$0}' file{,2}
```

Print which are the same different

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=",|"RS}FNR!=NR{print "cell"FNR (a[FNR]==$0?"":" not")" the same"}{a[NR]=$0}' file{,2}
```

---

#### Input

file

```
1,2,3,4,5  
6,7,8,9,10  
11,12,13,14,15
```

file2

```
1,2,3,4,5  
2,7,1,9,12  
1,1,1,1,12
```

---

#### Output

same

```
1
2
3
4
5
7
9
```

Different

```
2
1
12
1
1
1
1
12
```

Same different

```
cell1 the same
cell2 the same
cell3 the same
cell4 the same
cell5 the same
cell6 not the same
cell7 the same
cell8 not the same
cell9 the same
cell10 not the same
cell11 not the same
cell12 not the same
cell13 not the same
cell14 not the same
cell15 not the same
```